# sql inject me addon on links

Tags: mysql, sql-injection

I found a "mysql inject me" addon in firefox , which is really nice in finding mysql injection.

"mysql inject me" addon only test on forms of a page.
can i use it for testing mysql injections on links ?

Also what more can be altenatives ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "sqlmap" for link testing

python sqlmap.py -u 'url to test'